# Logo on the left, while text is centered and parallel to the logo

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put a logo on the top left corner, and text parallel to the logo (top center).
The text should have the same distance from both sides of the page regardless of the logo.

I tried adding around "display: table; display: table-cell; position: relative; position: absolute;"
But the best I can get is text being centered but not on the same line as the logo but a bit low.

html:

```
<header class="header">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="logo.gif" alt="a logo">
  </div>
  <div class="header-text">
    Some text that is supposed to be centered in viewport
  </div>
</header>
```

css:

```
.header {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100%;
}

.logo img {
  width: 80px;
}

.header-text {
  text-align: center;
}
```

example image:

[image]

Comment: Could you add a simple scetch (image) of what you want to accomplish?

Comment: I just did that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `position: absolute;` and i've added the position to the title and gave it a wrapper together with the image so you can move them together.

I've also added some margin to show you the title stays centered

```css
.header {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.logo {
  display: flex;
}

.logo img {
  width: 80px;
}

.header-text {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="a logo">
    </div>
    <div class="header-text">
      Some text that is supposed to be centered in viewport
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: The text is hugging top border. Should I align it with the logo by modifying the "top: 0;" or is there a way to automatically align the logo and the text in a combined way?

Comment: Ah yeah right sorry forgot about that im going to edit my answer

Comment: This works perfectly. But is it the standard or the best way of doing it?

Comment: The css is valid I've done this a few times and it never gave me problems further along the line. So I'd say yes.

Answer (score 2):

use flexbox!

```css
.header {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-items:center;
}

 img ,#spacer{
  width: 80px;
  
}

.header-text {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="a logo">
  
  <div class="header-text">
    Some text that is supposed to be centered in viewport
  </div>
  <div id='spacer'></div>
</header>
```

Comment: How would I make the text aligned with the logo and not hugging the top side? Should "vertical-align: middle;" go in there somewhere?

Comment: just add align-contents:center.  snippet adjusted

Answer (score 0):

There a numerous ways to go about this; I'll describe one method here.

Basically, you need to get the logo out of the layout flow so that the text can be centered without being affected by it. the easiest way to do this is by adding `position: absolute` to the logo.

Thus, a complete example might look like:

```css
.header {
  /* Allows the logo to be positioned relative to the header */
  position: relative;
  /* Centers the text — can be done other ways too */
  text-align: center;
}

.header .logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

A JSFiddle Example: https://jsfiddle.net/g01z27tv/.

---

### Keeping Proper Alignment

If you want to keep the logo and the text properly (vertically) aligned, flexbox will be your friend here.

First, ensure that the header is taller than the logo will be; otherwise the logo will be cut off.

Next, create a wrapper `<div>` for your logo. In your case:

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="logo-wrapper">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="logo.gif" alt="a logo">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- ... -->
</header>
```

Now, add some styles for `.logo-wrapper`. Namely:

- cause it to expand to fill the height of the header,
- make it a flex container,
- make its items' vertically centered,
- make it `position: absolute`, and
- position it to the left of the header:

```css
.logo-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

Note that you should now remove `position: absolute` and `left: 0` from `.logo`, since we are positioning the wrapper instead.

Lastly, in order to properly align the text, we'll use flexbox on `.header`:

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* Use this instead of text-align: center */
  align-items: center;
}
```

You'll note now that even when you make the logo taller—as long as the header is taller—everything stays aligned.

An Update JSFiddle Example: https://jsfiddle.net/oL5un8gb/.

*Note*: I created a separate wrapper `<div>` in this example; in your case you *probably* don't need to because you have a separate `<div>` and `<img>` already. You might be able to get it to work without an extra element.

Comment: In this case the text is centered but if I stylize the logo a bit (lets say add margin-top: 50px;) then the logo and text aren't parallel to each other anymore. How would I ensure that the two are always aligned? stylize both separately?

Comment: @Iber I updated by answer with information on aligning the header content using flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.header {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100%;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
}

.header-text {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.header::after {
      content: "";
      clear: both;
      display: table;
    }
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/75" alt="a logo">

  </div>
  <div class="header-text">
  Some text that is supposed to be centered in viewport
  </div>
</header>
```

As suggested in comments I have edited the text to be centred to 100% width.

Comment: Hi Nimm, this does not center the text inside the **viewport**

Comment: @RenevanderLende, the CSS is edited to match required. thanks for the comment.